# Enable external server access only through proxy?

Tags: java, apache, proxy

Setup: I have a deployed webapp on a server. And I have another machine which is a proxy.
Question: how can I ensure that the webserver can only be accessed through the proxy?

Eg: the user goes to `www.myproxy.com`, and is redirected to `www.mywebserver.com`

But he should not be able to access `www.mywebserver.com` directly without going first to the proxy.

Is that ever possible?

Comment: You could do this by checking the referrer, but that's not a good solution, because some browsers don't set the referrer, and it can be spoofed easily.

Comment: Could you explain what your need is? Proxies are generally used to allow access to network resources that don't otherwise have access to. Why do you need to prevent direct access to a server?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just came around that what I want is a so called "Reverse Proxy". So, a proxy that handles access to another webserver. But this webserver is not in the same network as the proxy. It has somehow a public ip, but should not be public and only accessible through the reverseproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, is your webserver always should be accessed through a reverse proxy or just redirect once?

If your webserver is always behind the proxy you should check the headers "Via" and "x-forwarded-for" on the web server.
the header via should contain your proxy server IP address.

Comment: Webserver and proxy are 2 different physical machines, that may be placed on different locations. So, not within the same network. I assume in this case I cannot say that the webserver is "behind the proxy"? Anyhow, that would be exactly what I want: make an external "public" server only reachable through the proxy. So, as if it would be really behind the proxy physically.

Comment: so my answer still apply, just check the headers "Via" and "x-forwarded-for"